# How to insert icons using drawable?

Tags: android

I have these drawable items:

```
<array name="bookmark_icons">
    <item>@drawable/google</item>
    <item>@drawable/android</item>
    <item>@drawable/offspot</item>
</array>
```

I want to insert these icons to my app. How can I do this?

These items must to appear at my ListView

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoritos_listView);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bookmark_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 doesn't have icon as well as android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2

You have to create your own list_item layout with ImageView and create custom adapter inserting images in your new  layout.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to create a custom listview using a listview. Hope the following link will help you.

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/